# How do i find the avg of a selected range in a row for pandas? Lets say i want only the mean from Jan to Apr,ive tried using the .mean function

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Code to get file and print values

```py
import csv

import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('Traffic_data.csv')

vehicle=df.loc[(df['Vehicle Type']=='Buses')]

print(vehicle)
```

Output of the above code.

```
  Vehicle Type    Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr  ...    Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dec

0        Buses  17037  17076  17093  17144  ...  17214  17238  17241  17223  17162
```

How can I get mean of selected month range (eg Jan to Apr)?

Answer (score 0):

You can select month columns needed and then transpose the dataframe
and then call mean

```py
import csv

import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('Traffic_data.csv')

vehicle=df.loc[(df['Vehicle Type']=='Buses')]

selectedMonths = vehicle[['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']]

selectedMonths = selectedMonths.T
print('data:')
display(selectedMonths)
print('------------------')
print('mean:')
selectedMonths.mean()
```

Output

```
data:
0
Jan 17037
Feb 17076
Mar 17093
Apr 17144
------------------
mean:
0    17087.5
dtype: float64
```